# How to put sidebar with ads only on full website but on mobile only show an ad every 4 posts

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a website where I need to display blog posts in a sidebar with ads. Surprisingly, the client want's a particular view on mobile devices that is killing me. The website small screen view needs to show 4 posts followed by an advertisement. Make this on two different website (one for mobile and another for desktop) is easily, but I can't make it using only bootstrap.

An example of the desired views are:

Desktop:

```
| post | post | ad  |  
| post | post | ad  |  
| post | post | ad  |
```

Mobile:

```
| post |  
| post |  
| post |  
| post |  
| ad   |
| post |  
| post |  
| post |  
| post |  
| ad   |  
| post |  
| post |  
| post |  
| post |  
| ad   |
```

It's difficult because if I make a 8 col for display posts and a 4 col for sidebar, in mobile view it doesn't view the way I want. On the other way, If I use 4 col for every continuous post, and then show an ad, the view in the full website will does't look good. Maybe in using hidden-* is the answer, but I'm thinking it.

Any help will be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a mixed grid configuration, that will format different on large devices (desktop) and small devices (mobile).

Start by checking the example at:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed

And them move foward until your final layout is ready.

You can even go further with different layouts for mobile, desktop and tablet:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed-complete

Comment: I'm currently using this, but I can't figure out how to make it work the way the client wants :(